# how to access the position variable of onbindviewholder() adapter class in other activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

*I want to fetch data from api using retrofit in recycler view im showing only shop name and timings when i click on the item in other activty i have to show the complete details of the shop for that i want position variable to fetch data of the position i selected*

```
      @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

                TextView textViewName = holder.textViewName;
                TextView textViewVersion = holder.textViewTime;
                textViewName.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getShop_name());
                textViewVersion.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getShop_time());
}
```

private  class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

```
    private final Context context;

    private MyOnClickListener(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ViewMoreActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    }
    public void fetchingData()
    {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait..");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

        Retrofit adapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constandapi.ROOT_URL)
                .build();

        ShopDetailsInterface report = adapter.create(ShopDetailsInterface.class);

        Call<ResponseBody> post_register;

        post_register = report.post_register("gow@gmail.com",
                "202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70","tw_puncture");
        post_register.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    try {

                        String result = response.body().string();

                        Log.d("resultdisplayLogin", "***   " + result);

                        JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(result);
                        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            DataModel dataModel = new DataModel();

                            dataModel.setShop_name(jsonObject.getString("shop_name"));
                            dataModel.setShop_time(jsonObject.getString("shop_time"));
                            data.add(dataModel);
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Log.d("datafetched", data+"");
                        }

                        detailadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }else
                {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"try Again........",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Does your fetch api contains only shop names and timings? Or it contains complete shop information?

Comment: it contains complete information i just want to access that variable to create json object of that position.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

Comment: at the place of i i have to pass position variable

Comment: make your custom `ViewHolder` implement `OnClickListener` and simply call in your `ViewHolder` constructor: `someView.setOnClickListener(this)`

Comment: ok i will try and let you inform it works or not

Comment: you can take onItemClickListener for recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

> how to access the position variable of onbindviewholder() adapter class in other activity

Assuming you Recyclerview has a viewHolder `MyViewHolder`

```
class MyViewHolder extends ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    // Assuming your row layout is having parent having id parent
    public MyViewHolder (View v) {
        super(v);
        parent = v.findViewByID(R.id.parentID);
        parent.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void OnClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition(); // Use this position 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an interface. It should contain a method like void onItemClick(int position);